# If $(-1) \cdot (-1) = +1$ shouldn't $(+1) \cdot (+1) = -1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The common multiplication rules are

$$(-1) \cdot (-1) = +1 \\ 
(+1) \cdot (+1) = +1$$

But these rules seem asymmetric. Because of these rules it is not possible e.g. to solve the equation
$$x^2 = -1 $$
without introducing complex numbers. There would be two "more symmetric" alternatives:

$$(-1) \cdot (-1) = -1 \\ 
(+1) \cdot (+1) = +1$$

or

$$(-1) \cdot (-1) = +1 \\ 
(+1) \cdot (+1) = -1$$

Both alternatives would allow to solve the equations
$$x^2 = +1 \\ x^2 = -1 $$
without the need to introduce complex numbers. However the two more symmetric alternatives are not used. What is the reason for that? Would math break down, if one would adopt one of these different conventions?

Comment: Then what would $(+1)\cdot (-1)$ be?

Comment: The number 1 has a very special role, if you multiply it onto any other number the same number results. This comes conceptually from the understanding of what multiplication is supposed to do on natural numbers.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon The most symmetric (commutative) solution would be $(+1) \cdot (-1) = 0$.

Comment: Symmetries are useful, but it makes no sense to construct symmetries, where no symmetries exist. Study Peter Ripota' site (The language is german, just use the words "ripota" and "symmetrie", click first hit) and look which problems can occur.

Comment: Is this voted down because the proposal is unreasonable? Is that a reason to vote down? Or is this maybe considered a troll question?

Comment: Answers show that your proposal violates standard rules of addition & distributivity, so it can't apply to our standard number system. **That's okay!** One of the neat things about math is it allows invention of new systems that impose *any rules you like*, provided they're *consistent*. (*Interesting* & *useful* are also nice, but those are subjective.) It remains *worthwhile* to explore whether *some* arithmetical system is consistent with your multiplication. You'll just need (at least) to abandon distributivity, and/or re-define addition, or who-knows-what ... but that's part of the *fun!*

Comment: $-u$ is the additive (group) inverse of $+u$. $+1$ is the neutral element of the multiplicative group. From that it can be shown that $(-1)\cdot (-1)=+1$.

Comment: If you worked $\mod 2$ then you would get the symmetry you seek. Course in that realm $1\equiv-1$ so it isn't that cute of a result really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some branches we do have that $1\cdot 1=-1$. However, the role of $1$ is *by definition* that of a neutral element of multiplication (like $0$ is neutral for addition), i.e., $1\cdot x=x\cdot 1=x$ holds (or is postulated to hold) for all $x$. So specifically $1\cdot 1=1$. This does not immediately contradict your idea of $1\cdot 1=-1$, it just implies $1=-1$ or in other words $2=0$. This equation does hold in the field $\Bbb F_2$ of two elements or more generally in fields of what is called characteristic $2$, which are widely applied for example in computer science and coding theory and other areas.

Apart from this way of sneaking away from the original question, it may be that your main problem comes from the introductory words "The common multiplication rules are..." In fact, what you cite then are *not* the common *basic* rules (or axioms) of multiplication, which are instead
$$ a\cdot(b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c,\qquad (a+b)\cdot c=(a\cdot c)+(b\cdot c),\quad a\cdot(b+c)=(a\cdot b)+(a\cdot c).$$
We can *infer* the rest from these. Specifically, the properties of *addition* force us to accept that $0\cdot a=a\cdot 0=0$ for all $a$: From $0+0=0$ and distributivity we see that $0\cdot a=(0+0)\cdot a=0\cdot a+0\cdot a$, hence $0\cdot a=0$ and similarly for the other order. As a consequence of this, we have $a\cdot b+a\cdot c=0$ whenever $b+c=0$, i.e. $a\cdot(-b)=-(a\cdot b)$ (and similarly $(-a)\cdot b=-(a\cdot b)$). So at any rate $(-a)\cdot(-a)+a\cdot(-a)=0$ and $a\cdot a+a\cdot (-a)=0$ and consequently $$(-a)\cdot(-a)=a\cdot a.$$

Comment: @If he wants $1\cdot 1=-1$ he cannot mean the real numbers

Answer (score 7):

A lot of math would break down if you use that, yes. For example, with our multiplication, we have the property that for any three numbers $a,b,c$, we have $$a(b+c) = ab + bc$$

This would not hold anymore in your case, since

$$0 = -1\cdot 0 = -1\cdot (1 + (-1)) \neq 1\cdot (-1) + (-1)\cdot (-1) = -1 -1 =-2$$

This is assuming that the new multiplication is still commutative and that $1$ is still the "*unit*" of multiplication, i.e. that $1\cdot x = x$ for all $x$.

---

In fact, all you need to prove that $(-1)\cdot (-1) = 1$ is the rule $a(b+c) = ab+bc$, and the property that $1\cdot x = x$, since you can see that if this rule is true, then

$$0 = (-1)\cdot 0 = (-1)\cdot (1+(-1)) = (-1)\cdot 1 + (-1)\cdot(-1) $$

which means that $0=(-1)\cdot (-1) + (-1)\cdot 1$ or in other words that $(-1)\cdot (-1) = 1$.

Comment: The assumpotion that $1$ is still the unit makes things break down much faster as it *immediately* demands $1\cdot 1=1$.

Comment: If one worked $\mod 2$ things would still be fine though as $-2\equiv0$

Answer (score 2):

The rules $(-1)\cdot(-1)=1$ and $1 \cdot 1 = 1$ aren't *conventions*.  They are *consequences* of how we define our number system: specifically, of what multiplication is, and what the symbol $-1$ means.

You can, if you like, define brand new operations, with different symbols, obeying different rules, and study the properties of such systems.  That is in fact what group theory is all about.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a very "naive" way of answering this question.**

---

When trying to define the following:

1. Positive $\times$ Positive $=$?
2. Positive $\times$ Negative $=$?
3. Negative $\times$ Positive $=$?
4. Negative $\times$ Negative $=$?

We first need to ensure that the answers to #2 and #3 are identical.

This is because multiplication is **commutative** ($\forall a,b:a\times b=b\times a$).

---

Let's arbitrarily define:

- Positive $\times$ Negative $=$ Negative
- Negative $\times$ Positive $=$ Negative

As you can see:

- In the output, the sign of the positive input has been inverted
- In the output, the sign of the negative input has been preserved

Following this "behavior", the answers to #1# and #4 are clear:

- Positive $\times$ Positive $=$ Positive
- Negative $\times$ Negative $=$ Positive

---

Of course, we could always arbitrarily define:

- Positive $\times$ Negative $=$ Positive
- Negative $\times$ Positive $=$ Positive

And subsequently:

- Positive $\times$ Positive $=$ Negative
- Negative $\times$ Negative $=$ Negative

But that would only make a semantic swap between "positive" and "negative".

Comment: Could one not assume Positive × Negative == Zero and Negative × Positive == Zero ?

Comment: @asmaier: One could assume Positive $\times$ Negative $=$ Monkey, but that would introduce a whole bunch of other conflicts while trying to build up a concise set of rules. BTW, "zero" was not a part of your question.

Comment: If Positive $\times$ Negative $=$ Monkey, does $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n$ contain the works of Shakespeare?

Answer (score 0):

Math would certainly break down, here's why. Assume that every number is equal to itself, addition is associative, multiplication distributes over addition , $1$ and $-1$ are additive inverses, $1$ is the multiplicative identity, and $0$ is the additive identity. Then it follows that:
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\bigg(1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot (-1)\bigg) + (-1)\cdot(-1) &=& \bigg(1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot (-1)\bigg) + (-1)\cdot(-1)\\
\bigg(1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot (-1)\bigg) + (-1)\cdot(-1) &=& 1\cdot 1 + \bigg(1\cdot (-1) + (-1)\cdot(-1)\bigg)\\
1\bigg(1+(-1)\bigg) + (-1)\cdot(-1) &=& 1\cdot 1 + (-1)\bigg(1 + (-1)\bigg)\\
1\bigg(0\bigg) + (-1)\cdot(-1) &=& 1\cdot 1 + (-1)\bigg(0\bigg)\\
0 + (-1)\cdot(-1) &=& 1\cdot 1 + 0\\
(-1)\cdot(-1) &=& 1\cdot 1 \\
\end{array}$$

The only loose end not assumed above is  $(-1)\cdot 0 = 0$

$$(-1)\cdot 0 = (-1)(0+0)$$
$$(-1)\cdot 0 = (-1)\cdot 0+ (-1)\cdot 0$$
$$\dots$$